# ¿Qué significa "ese juguito e' parcha que te..."?

Tags: coloquialismos, comida, hispanoamérica, letras-de-canciones, identificación-de-término

Hay una canción que traigo de cantar. No puedo recordar las palabras si no las entiendo. La frase que no entiendo es:

> Soy ese juguito e' parcha que te baja la presión

¿Cuál sería la frase sin abreviatura? ¿Y qué significa? (Tal vez lo entendería sin la abreviacion *e'* pero no me parece evidente). Entiendo ya que *juguito* es "a little drink" y *que te baja la presion* es "that calms you down".

La canción entera se llama "La Complicidad", de Perota Chingo.

> Soy la serenidad que lleva a la meditación
>   Y tu eres ese tan sagrado mantra
>   **Soy ese juguito e' parcha que te baja la presión**
>   y siempre que te sube tu me llamas Ya
>   tira la sábana sal de la cama
>   vamos a conquistar toda la casa

["Perota Chingo: La Complicidad'](https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=2060961)

Comment: Primero la canción no es de "Perota Chingo" (Uruguay) es de la autoría de "Cultura Profética" una banda originaria de Puerto Rico (Por ende se confirma que dice "juguito e' parcha" la fruta). Comento porque en una versión grabada de esta canción interpretada por Perota Chingo he oído que lo pronuncian mal diciendo "JUEguito e' parcha" y me entro curiosidad saber si el que estaba mal era yo. Saludos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La Wikipedia nos desvela que la [parcha](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passiflora_edulis) es una fruta exótica:

[image]

> El maracuyá, mburukuja, pasionaria, parcha, parchita, chinola o mburucuyá (Passiflora edulis) es una planta trepadora del género Passiflora.

El DAMER revela que [*parcha*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=parcha) también quiere decir *homosexual* en Venezuela, pero [las artistas parecen ser de Argentina](http://tn.com.ar/musica/clips/perota-chingo-de-argentina-al-mundo_101020), luego dudo que tenga ese sentido.

En el artículo [La parcha, fruta exótica](http://www.informeagricola.com/la-parcha-fruta-exotica/) mencionan que:

> Además ayuda a bajar la presión y esta es una de las razones por la cual los consumidores la utilizan con mayor frecuencia.

Por lo que el fragmento *que te baja la presión* cobra aún más sentido. Además, nótese que *jugo* y su diminutivo *juguito* son comunes en Hispanoamérica (en España decimos *zumo*).

Finalmente, el uso de *e'* para referirse a *de* parece un recurso para simbolizar que la preposición se dice tan rápido que la consonante *d* apenas suena (yo no la oí al escuchar la canción). Esto lo explica el DPD en su entrada [*apóstrofo*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=wV8heEHVFD64FHx2Ng):

> *apóstrofo*. Signo ortográfico auxiliar en forma de coma alta (’), que apenas se usa en el español actual.
>
> 1. Como usos propios de la lengua española, se distinguen principalmente dos:
>
> a) ...
>
> b) Para reflejar, en la escritura, la supresión de sonidos que se produce en ciertos niveles de la lengua oral. Aparece con frecuencia en textos literarios cuando el autor desea reproducir el habla de personajes de escasa cultura: *«Sacúdete el vestidito, m’ija, pa’que se nos salga el mal agüero»* (Hayen Calle [Méx. 1993]).

Así pues, la frase:

> Soy ese juguito e' parcha que te baja la presión

Se puede reescribir a:

> Soy ese zumo de maracuyá que te hipotensa

Si bien no creo que suene tan bien :-)

Comment: ¿Por qué no quitas la acepción venezolana para hacer tu respuesta más sucinta?

Comment: @aparente001 no creo que sea necesario. La referencia al Diccionario de americanismos me parece importante en casos así y desechar opciones creo que también es parte de la utilidad de la respuesta para no dejar flecos sueltos.

Answer (score 1):

Es una clara alusión sexual. Yo soy aquel que te alivia cuando tienes ganas. Es una bella manera de decir que me llamas para que lo hagamos en cualquier parte, no solo en la cama. Mi traducción es cruda, pero la estrofa es bella.

Comment: Bueno, "juguito de parcha" no es en sí una alusión sexual (mira la otra ]respuesta la pregunta que explica lo que es la parcha](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21918/5481)). Lo es (quizá) en el **contexto** de esta canción. Probablemente sí que "te baja la presión" == alivio sexual.  Siéntete bienvenido a [Spanish.se], pero tal vez quieras revisar [tour], [help] y [answer] para entender un poco mejor cómo funciona este sitio. En lugar de decir "está claro que [...]" es mejor _explicarlo_. Para otros puede no estar tan claro, y es bueno explicar el **por qué** de cada cosa.